# Conditional breakpoint on a funtion's return value in lldb?

Tags: lldb

I searched but can't find a good solution. Is that possible,why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LLDB doesn't support breakpoint commands that can run the debugee a bit and then perform further steps.  The breakpoint commands terminate when the debugee starts up again.  So you can't use breakpoint commands to do this.  This is a restriction that will be fixed at some point but it is not a trivial piece of work.

However, lldb also has a "scripted step" feature that allows you to craft your own custom step operations.  You could use that to work around this restriction.  The FinishPrintAndContinue in the examples file:

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/python/scripted_step.py

is almost what you want.  You just need to change the continue to check the return value (using SBThread::GetStopReturnValue) and then continuing or stopping depending on the result.  Then you could put a breakpoint on the function in question and adds a command that runs this fancy step.

Comment: This still too hard for me, but thank you for you reply.